# How to properly configure the `services.AddDbContext` of `ConfigureServices` method

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm trying to run an .NET Core Web application with EF Core. In order to test the repository I've added an `MyDbContext` that inherits the EF `DbContext` and interface `IMyDbContext`.

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
    DbSet<MyModel> Models { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyModel> Models { get; set; }
}
```

The context interface is injected to my generic repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly IMyDbContext _context = null;

    public GenericRepository(IMyDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }
}
```

When I use this code (without the interface) on startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(...));
```

I'm getting a run-time error of:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'IMyDbContext' while attempting to activate 'GenericRepository`1[MyModel]'

And when using this line of code:

```
services.AddDbContext<IMyDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(...));
```

I'm getting this compiled time error code of:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceLifetime' because it
>   is not a delegate type

**My question is how to properly configure the `services.AddDbContext` of `ConfigureServices` method?**
(Is there any changes needed inside `Configure` method?)
If needed I'm willing to modify the IMyDbContext

Comment: Add curly braces to get rid of compile error

Comment: Dont' use `IMyDbContext`

Comment: And I would not bother interfacing DbContext and instead use AddDbContext<YourDbContext>

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I need it to unit testing

Comment: Use in memory database for unit testing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use one of the [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-2.1) having 2 generic type arguments, which allow you to specify both the service interface/class you want to register as well as the `DbContext` derived class implementing it.

For instance:

```
services.AddDbContext<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(...));
```

Comment: Hey @Ivan, It looks like clean and nice answer but it creates an exception: `Could not resolve a service of type 'MyDbContext' for the parameter 'modelsDbContext' of method 'Configure' on type 'Startup'.

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'MyDbContext' has been registered.`

Comment: Well, the above is all I can tell from EF Core point of view. The new exception indicates that you have direct dependency to `MyDbContext` in a code not shown in the post.

Answer (score 5):

Just found the answer:

I was missing the adding of the scope between `IMyDbContext` and `MyDbContext`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{                    
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(...));
    services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<MyModel>, GenericRepository<MyModel>>();
    services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>();
}
```