# System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service - .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, middleware, asp.net-core-6.0

I have just added Middleware to my codes which giving this error when I wanted to run it

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'HORA_API.Model.AGUSContext' from root provider.'`

[image: program.cs]

this is the program.cs

```
global using HORA_API.Model;
using HORA_API.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AGUSContext>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

 //app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Appreciate any help on this. thank you

edited to add :

Full details of the exception

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Cannot resolve scoped service 'HORA_API.Model.AGUSContext' from root provider.
> Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0(RequestDelegate next)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.b__27_0(RequestDelegate next)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.d__37.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.d__12.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)
> at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Hora vs 090123\api\HORA-API\HORA-API\Program.cs:line 30

Middleware codes

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, AGUSContext dataService)
{
    var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();

    if (token != null)
        attachUserToContext(context, dataService, token);

    await _next(context);
}

private void attachUserToContext(HttpContext context, AGUSContext dataService, string token)
{
    try
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SecretToken");
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

        var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
        var email = jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "id").Value;

        // attach user to context on successful jwt validation
        var useremail = dataService.Otps.FirstOrDefault(v => v.AlamatEmail == email);
        if (useremail != null)
        {
            context.Items["User"] = "Ok";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // do nothing if jwt validation fails
        // user is not attached to context so request won't have access to secure routes
    }
```

Attribute Authorization

```
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Items["User"] == null)
    {
        // not logged in
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
    }
}
```

Then i added this on the controller

```
  private string generateJwtToken(string email)
    {
        // generate token that is valid for 7 days
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(otpcode);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("id", email) }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Comment: What’s the full exception message?

Comment: What is the middleware you're adding?

Comment: @stuartd I edited to include the details thank you

Comment: @itsdaniel0 edited to include the middleware codes

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532595/how-to-properly-configure-the-services-adddbcontext-of-configureservices-met) helps.

Comment: How do you register the middleware?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984052/can-i-add-a-new-scoped-service-within-a-custom-middleware is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Injecting the middleware will resolve it from the root lifetime, which doesn't have access to the scope.
Resolve it from the context provider instead, which has access to the scope

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    // Resolve the context
    var dataService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<AGUSContext>();
    var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();

    if (token != null)
        attachUserToContext(context, dataService, token);

    await _next(context);
}
```